# AngularJs watch in a menu controller

Tags: angularjs, watch

I'm using a watch to maintain states in a submenu.

In the menu I have:

```
$scope.$watch('$stateParams.colonyId', function(newVal, oldVal) {
...
}
```

It worked before - not anymore. It doesn't throw any errors and `newVal` and `oldVal` are undefined. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can try ton inject `$state` into your controller and use `$watch` on `$state.params`

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $state.params.colonyId;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        alert('Value changed !');
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, you can then validate my answer. And feel free to upvote as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it won't work is because the `$stateParams` service is not on your `$scope` object. The notation of `$scope.$watch("someProperty",..)` expects that `someProperty` is on your `$scope` object.

To fix this either register your `$stateParams` service on your `$scope` (Don't recommend!), or change your watch to watch a function instead:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $stateParams.colonyId;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    ...
}
```